# Turning \answerline into a box in exam class

Tags: exam, box

I've been a big fan of the exam class, and use it often to write tests. I'd like to be able to turn `\answerline` into a box instead, while retaining the ability to use `answers` to toggle the solutions. Ideally, I'd also be able to set the width and the height globally, while having the option to override it for a given question. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question This is a question. \answerline
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be able to use the built in  solutionorbox environment `\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]  Test  \end{solutionorbox}` gives a 3cm tall box to write in or displays a box with `Solution: Test` inside it. The box width depends on the type of question (main or part etc.).

Comment: @Jon I've tried that, however, it always seems that it produces a full width box below the question itself. I'm looking for something that puts it to the right, on the same line as the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically copied the definition of `\answerline`.  The box is larger due to the `\fboxsep` gap on all sides, but I figured it was more important to fit the answer into the given space.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\answerbox[1][{}]{%
  % One optional argument, the default value of which is empty.
  \ifx\@queslevel\ques@ref
    \let\ans@l=\questionlabel
  \else
    \ifx\@queslevel\part@ref
      \let\ans@l=\partlabel
    \else
      \ifx\@queslevel\subpart@ref
        \let\ans@l=\subpartlabel
      \else
        \ifx\@queslevel\subsubpart@ref
          \let\ans@l=\subsubpartlabel
        \else
          % Oops; no question level defined.
          % We must be outide of the questions environment.
          % Just leave out the label, I guess:
          \def\ans@l{}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \par \nobreak \vskip \answerskip
  \hfill 
  \ifprintanswers
    \ans@l~\fbox{\hbox to \answerlinelength{%
      % 2016/05/10: Added \color@begingroup and \color@endgroup:
      \color@begingroup
      \CorrectChoice@Emphasis \hfil #1\hss
      \color@endgroup}}%
  \else
    \ans@l~\fbox{\strut\hspace{\answerlinelength}}%
  \fi
  \par
}% answerbox
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question This is a question. \answerline[with answer]
    \question How high is up? \answerbox[with answer]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```